# Spark&Zepplin: How to use "Connect to existing process" feature?

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, apache-zeppelin

I have a running instance of docker with zeppelin/spark environment configured. I would like to know if there is a possibility to run spark-shell process for example with

`docker exec -it CONTAINTER spark-shell`

and then connect to created spark context with zeppelin notebook. I've seen that there is a "Connect to existing process" checkbox in the Zeppelin interpreters page, however I'm not sure how to use it.

For example, in Jupyter notebook there is a possibility to connect ipython console to an existing Jupyter kernel such that I have access to the notebook variables from ipython console. I'm wondering if there is a similar functionality in case of Zeppeling and spark-shell or maybe for some reasons this is not possible. 
Thank you in advance. 
KK